# can magnesium chloride and iodine react together?

Tags: solutions

If everything is in a mixture of alcohol and water, would it be possible for magnesium chloride and iodine to react and produce something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnesium chloride and Iodine with form an equilibrium.  This is a bit of a simplification of the reactions but the dissociated chlorides and free iodine will reversibly react to form iodide and triiodide ions and chlorine.
$$\ce{Cl- + 1/2 I2 <=> 1/2 Cl2 + I-} $$
$$\ce{MgCl2 + I2 <=> MgI2 + Cl2} $$
$$\ce{I- + I2 <=> I3-} $$
$$\ce{MgI2 + 2I <=> Mg(I3)2} $$
The amount of products of this reaction though will not be very appreciable, but yes a very literal sense magnesium chloride and iodine will react.

Comment: `$\ce{<=>}$` gives you the correct arrows: $\ce{<=>}$

Comment: what do you mean by not be very appreciable? Could you quantify it generally?

Comment: That would be pretty negligible. On the same grounds you may claim that **any** two compounds react with each other, which also would be technically true in some sense.

Comment: Looking at it macroscopically, the first two equilibria are so far on the reactants’ side, that one would say ‘no reaction is observed’.

Comment: (-1): Disagree. See my explanation and source.

Comment: Would someone like to provide a reference here.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, elemental iodine does not displace chloride!

Per [an educational source](https://www.flinnsci.com/api/library/Download/276267f4675548e9ad8122f2062864ee), for example, to quote:

> These reactions will take place in one direction only. The reaction of a halogen X2 with a different sodium halide (NaY) will occur only if X2 is more reactive than Y2. If X2 is less reactive than Y2, the reaction shown in Equation 1 will not take place.

However, in the real world, does this mean that in the presence of a transition metal impurity (say iron in the form of ferrous as found in tap water) is it likely that aqueous $\ce{MgCl2}$ is unreactive with an iodine presence?

To answer, I will explore some advanced [fenton-type chemistry](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0003267002014356) (which could be subject to recycling with light).

Consider the reaction between ferrous and HOI formed in the first step with the reaction of iodine and water:

$\ce{I2 (s) + H2O (l) <=> H+ + I- + HOI}$

$\ce{Fe(2+) + HOI -> Fe(3+) + .IOH-}$

And, at pH over 5 (assuming chemistry paralleling that of the [chlorine-based $\ce{.ClOH-}$ radical anion](https://www.bnl.gov/isd/documents/92710.pdf)):

$\ce{.IOH- -> .OH + I-}$

$\ce{Cl- + .OH -> .Cl + OH-}$ [(Source)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11513408/)

$\ce{.Cl + .Cl -> Cl2}$

But, at pH under 5:

$\ce{.IOH- -> .I + OH-}$

implying likely no chlorine creation.

Note, per photolysis:

$\ce{I- + hv -> .I + e-}$

which could recycle iron ions:

$\ce{Fe(3+) + e- -> Fe(2+)}$.

Also, any ferric iodide formed is unstable and reverts to ferrous, which creates a cyclical clock reaction system ([discussed here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ed085p1123)).

Bottom line, in my assessment, except with favorable impurities, pH and light, it is not likely that any free chlorine, as an intermediate, would be formed in a system of MgCl2 and I2.